# Why do the Handlers on Flutter's Xlider Range Slider keep snapping back after I drag them?

Tags: flutter, dart, slider, audio-player

I'm trying to use Xlider to control Flutter's `Audioplayers` plugin.But every time I try to drag either handler on Flutter's `Xlider` Range Slider they pop back to the edges. I'm passing the Duration of a recorded file to `Audioplayers` via the `Flutter Audio Recorder` plugin as `final Duration recordedDuration`. This recorded duration is converted to a double and used as the "end" variable in Xlider's values parameter. When the `_durationSubscription` senses a change in duration,(when a new audio file has been recorded) I do a setState of `recordedDuration = duration`. This seems to get the correct start and end values into Xlider. From there, I'd like any changes in the lower handler to change the start position for playback of the audioplayer. But unfortunately when I put any audio function such as;

```
`_audioPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds:600));`
```

The handlers will not stick to the position where they are dragged and snap back to the outside edges. Here's the whole code;

```
  class PlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  final PlayerMode mode;
  final Duration recordedDuration;

  const PlayerWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.url,
    this.mode = PlayerMode.MEDIA_PLAYER,
    required this.recordedDuration
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _PlayerWidgetState(url, mode, recordedDuration);
  }
}

class _PlayerWidgetState extends State<PlayerWidget> {
  String url;
  PlayerMode mode;
  Duration recordedDuration;
  late AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;
  PlayerState? _audioPlayerState;
  Duration _duration = Duration(microseconds: 1);
  Duration _position = Duration(microseconds: 1);
  PlayerState _playerState = PlayerState.STOPPED;

  StreamSubscription? _durationSubscription;
  StreamSubscription? _positionSubscription;
  StreamSubscription? _playerCompleteSubscription;
  StreamSubscription? _playerErrorSubscription;
  StreamSubscription? _playerStateSubscription;
  StreamSubscription<PlayerControlCommand>? _playerControlCommandSubscription;
  bool get _isPlaying => _playerState == PlayerState.PLAYING;
  _PlayerWidgetState(this.url, this.mode, this.recordedDuration);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initAudioPlayer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _audioPlayer.dispose();
    _durationSubscription?.cancel();
    _positionSubscription?.cancel();
    _playerCompleteSubscription?.cancel();
    _playerErrorSubscription?.cancel();
    _playerStateSubscription?.cancel();
    _playerControlCommandSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double durationToDouble = recordedDuration.inMilliseconds.toDouble();
    double start = 1;
    double end = durationToDouble;

    return FlutterSlider(
      trackBar: FlutterSliderTrackBar(),
      handler: FlutterSliderHandler(
        child: Icon(Icons.chevron_left, color: Colors.black, size: 32),
      ),
      rightHandler: FlutterSliderHandler(
        child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right, color: Colors.black, size: 32),
      ),
      values: [start, end],
      min: 1,
      max: recordedDuration.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
      rangeSlider: true,
      step: FlutterSliderStep(step: 1),
      onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {},
      onDragCompleted:(handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue){           
        _audioPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds:600));
      },
    );
  }

   void _initAudioPlayer() {
    _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(mode: mode);
    _durationSubscription = _audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((duration) {
      setState(() {
        _duration = duration;
        recordedDuration = duration;
      });
      });

    _positionSubscription =
        _audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((p) => setState(() {
          _position = p;
        }));

    _playerCompleteSubscription =
        _audioPlayer.onPlayerCompletion.listen((event) {
          _onComplete();
          setState(() {
            _position = _duration;
          });
        });

    _playerErrorSubscription = _audioPlayer.onPlayerError.listen((msg) {
       setState(() {
        _playerState = PlayerState.STOPPED;
        _duration = const Duration();
        _position = const Duration();
      });
    });

    _playerControlCommandSubscription =
        _audioPlayer.notificationService.onPlayerCommand.listen((command) {
          print('command: $command');
        });

    _audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _audioPlayerState = state;
        });
      }
    });

    _audioPlayer.onNotificationPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() => _audioPlayerState = state);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<int> _play() async {
    _duration = recordedDuration;
    final playPosition = (_position != null &&
        _duration != null &&
        _position.inMilliseconds > 0 &&
        _position.inMilliseconds < _duration.inMilliseconds)
        ? _position
        : null;
    final result = await _audioPlayer.play(url, position: playPosition);
    if (result == 1) {
      setState(() {
        _playerState = PlayerState.PLAYING;
      });
    }
    _audioPlayer.setPlaybackRate();

    return result;
  }

  Future<int> _pause() async {
    final result = await _audioPlayer.pause();
    if (result == 1) {
      setState(() {
        _playerState = PlayerState.PAUSED;
       });
    }
    return result;
  }
  void _onComplete() {
     setState(() {
      _playerState = PlayerState.STOPPED;
    });
  }
}
```

How do I make the handlers stay put after I've dragged them? Why can't I use `onDragCompleted` to trigger any kind of audioplayer function?

Comment: Because you are not updating the ```values: [start, end],``` ? try to update these values inside your ```setState()```

Comment: I did this but no luck; setState(() {
                      start = lowerValue;
                      end= upperValue;
                    });

Comment: Did you put it inside ```onDragCompleted``` or ```onDragging``` ? second one is the correct place

Comment: I triedboth. Neither work.

Comment: Please post all your class to check specially your build

Comment: It's weird because if I remove everything from onDragCompleted andr onDragging and just leave it empy, it works. But the minute I add something like _audioPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds:600));   The handlers snap back.

Comment: OK. I've added the entire Class.

Comment: Move ```double start = 1;``` outside your ```build``` declare it where you have all your variables like ```String url;```

Comment: and keep ```setState()``` inside ```onDragging``` to update ```start``` and ```end```

Comment: That worked for the start but not the end. I tried to put double durationToDouble = recordedDuration.inMilliseconds.toDouble(); outside the build too but it wouldn't let me put it inside an initializer.

Comment: Try to use ```double end = _position.inMilliseconds.toDouble()``` instead of ```recordedDuration```

Comment: Android studio tells me "The instance member '_position' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression" It's odd because I've declared "Duration _position = Duration(microseconds: 1);" just before it.

Comment: keep this inside your build don't move it outside (move only the start)

Comment: if I keep it inside the build the handle snaps back. So I created this function. _getEnd(){
    end = recordedDuration.inMilliseconds.toDouble();
  } and am looking into where I can call it.

Comment: You are setting the max and end as ```recordedDuration``` and in the meantime you are updating this ```recordedDuration```, probably you are using the wrong value to set your end/max

Comment: The max shoul d be the recordedDuration but not sure about the end.

Comment: Ok. seems the trick was to put  _upperValue = recordedDuration.inMilliseconds.toDouble(); within the setstate of durationSubscription = _audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((duration)

Comment: I spoke too soon. Putting that under the duration listener makes it change too often.